# pandas: How do I enforce that die faces of type np.int8 stored in the index of a pandas data frame remain of type np.int8?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I create a numpy array of die faces of type `np.int8`. I create a pandas data frame with an index of those die faces and a weights column of ones. I try to set the type of the die faces in the index to `np.int8`. The first element of the index is of type np.int64.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
array_of_die_faces = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype = np.int8)
array_of_weights = np.ones(len(array_of_die_faces))
data_frame_of_faces_and_weights = pd.DataFrame({'weight': array_of_weights}, index = array_of_die_faces)
data_frame_of_faces_and_weights.index = data_frame_of_faces_and_weights.index.astype(dtype = np.int8)
face = data_frame_of_faces_and_weights.index[0]
print(type(face))
```

Comment: Please do not use images of code, provide reproducible **text**.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported. You cannot convert your index to int8:

```
data_frame_of_faces_and_weights.index.astype(np.int8)
```

Or

```
pd.Index(array_of_die_faces, dtype=np.int8)
```

both result in:

```
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

There is a plan to remove [`Int64Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Index.html) to replace it with `NumericIndex`:

> Deprecated since version 1.4.0: In pandas v2.0 Int64Index will be
> removed and `NumericIndex` used instead. Int64Index will remain fully
> functional for the duration of pandas 1.x.

but you will have to wait some more time.